# "last name, first name" -> "first name last name" in serialized strings

Tags: regex, string, r

I have a bunch of strings that contain lists of names in **last name, first name** format, separated by commas, like so:

```
names <- c('Beaufoy, Simon, Boyle, Danny','Nolan, Christopher','Blumberg, Stuart, Cholodenko, Lisa','Seidler, David','Sorkin, Aaron')
```

What's the easiest way to convert all these names within the strings to **first name last name** format?

Comment: Is it always going to be pairs of names, or will there be people with more than just two names?

Comment: You mean something like "Hoover, J. Edgar"? Could be. It's really unfortunate that the same separator has been used to separate last from first name and names from other sames. But that's the way it is, I'm afraid. What's true (I hope...) is that commas don't appear within a first or a last name.

Comment: I think his example had some quotes missing. If single element contains more than 1 name then probably there would be lot of work (spliting and recombining to form unique name and so forth) to do before you can do simple regex.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Or is your question how many names will be in each string? In that case, the answer is that there might be one, there might be many more.

Comment: @ChinmayPatil Nope, the example is exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can be certain that a comma isn't going to be in a person's name, this might work:

```
mynames <- c('Beaufoy, Simon, Boyle, Danny',
             'Nolan, Christopher',
             'Blumberg, Stuart, Cholodenko, Lisa',
             'Seidler, David',
             'Sorkin, Aaron',
             'Hoover, J. Edgar')
mynames2 <- strsplit(mynames, ", ")

unlist(lapply(mynames2, 
              function(x) paste(x[1:length(x) %% 2 == 0], 
                                x[1:length(x) %% 2 != 0])))
# [1] "Simon Beaufoy"     "Danny Boyle"       "Christopher Nolan"
# [4] "Stuart Blumberg"   "Lisa Cholodenko"   "David Seidler"    
# [7] "Aaron Sorkin"      "J. Edgar Hoover"
```

I've added J. Edgar Hoover in there for good measure.

If you want the names that were quoted together to stay together, add `collapse = ", "` to your `paste()` function:

```
unlist(lapply(mynames2, 
              function(x) paste(x[1:length(x) %% 2 == 0], 
                                x[1:length(x) %% 2 != 0],
                                collapse = ", ")))
# [1] "Simon Beaufoy, Danny Boyle"       "Christopher Nolan"               
# [3] "Stuart Blumberg, Lisa Cholodenko" "David Seidler"                   
# [5] "Aaron Sorkin"                     "J. Edgar Hoover"
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you! Any way to put the strings back together again at the end?

Answer (score 4):

**(1) Maintain same names in each element** This can be done with a single `gsub` (assuming there are no commas within names):

```
> gsub("([^, ][^,]*), ([^,]+)", "\\2 \\1", names)
[1] "Simon Beaufoy, Danny Boyle"       "Christopher Nolan"               
[3] "Stuart Blumberg, Lisa Cholodenko" "David Seidler"                   
[5] "Aaron Sorkin"    

> gsub("([^, ][^,]*), ([^,]+)", "\\2 \\1", "Hoover, J. Edgar")
[1] "J. Edgar Hoover"
```

**(2) Separate into one name per element** If you wanted each first name last name in a separate element then use **(a) scan**

```
scan(text = out, sep = ",", what = "")
```

where `out` is the result of the `gsub` above or to get it directly try **(b) strapply**:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(names, "([^, ][^,]*), ([^,]+)", x + y ~ paste(y, x), simplify = c)
[1] "Simon Beaufoy"     "Danny Boyle"       "Christopher Nolan"
[4] "Stuart Blumberg"   "Lisa Cholodenko"   "David Seidler"    
[7] "Aaron Sorkin"     

> strapply("Hoover, Edgar J.", "([^, ][^,]*), ([^,]+)", x + y ~ paste(y, x), 
+   simplify = c)
[1] "Edgar J. Hoover"
```

Note that all examples above used the same regular expression for matching.

UPDATE: removed comma separating first and last name.

UPDATE: added code to separate out each first name last name into a separate element in case that is the preferred output format.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation. I'd upmod this more if I could!

Comment: That's pretty cool. It didn't occur to me that the regex would work in that way, so I didn't bother to try it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of @AnandaMahto's Answer, but just for fun, this illustrates another method using `scan`, `split`, and `rapply`.

```
names <- c(names, 'Chambers, John, Ihaka, Ross, Gentleman, Robert')

# extract names
snames <- 
lapply(names, function(x) scan(text=x, what='', sep=',', strip.white=TRUE, quiet=TRUE))

# break up names
snames<-lapply(snames, function(x) split(x, rep(seq(length(x) %/% 2), each=2)))

# collapse together, reversed
rapply(snames, function(x) paste(x[2:1], collapse=' '))
```