# Last name, First Name to First name Last name on iOS

Tags: regex

["last name, first name" -> "first name last name" in serialized strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485060/last-name-first-name-first-name-last-name-in-serialized-strings)

I want to do the same thing on iOS. Using the Workflow app, or Drafts or Editorial.

I have Googled, searched here and tested various regex commands but I couldn't get anything to work.

Briefly, there's is say a list of names in the format Y, X and I want to change it to X Y using regex.

Comment: You should show inputs and outputs

Comment: try replacing `(.*), (.*)` with `$2 $1`

Comment: Bohemian, that worked in Drafts! I had been trying several combinations of something like ^([^,],). I suppose I must have tried the simpler (.*), (.*) with \2\s\1 or \2 \1 instead of $2 $1. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked in Drafts is by Bohemian above.

```
    Replace (.*), (.*) with $2 $1 – Bohemian
```