# Changing "firstname lastname" to "lastname, firstname"

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a list of names that I need to convert from "Firstname Lastname" to "Lastname, Firstname".

```
Barack Obama
Donald J. Trump
J. Edgar Hoover
Beyonce Knowles-Carter
Sting
```

I used G. Grothendieck's answer to ["last name, first name" -> "first name last name" in serialized strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485060/last-name-first-name-first-name-last-name-in-serialized-strings?rq=1) to get to `gsub("([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)", "\\2, \\1", str)` which gives me -

```
Obama, Barack
J., DonaldTrump, 
Edgar, J.Hoover, 
Knowles-Carter, Beyonce
Sting
```

What I would like to get -

```
Obama, Barack
Trump, Donald J. 
Hoover, J. Edgar
Knowles-Carter, Beyonce
Sting
```

I would like a regex answer.

Comment: How do you determine what the last name has two or more separated words as it is often seen in arabic countries? An example would be "Qaboos bin Said al Said"

Comment: @loki, this question was aimed at being more general about splitting names into Firstname and Lastname but I am not sure if we can address all patterns of names. @AkselA has provided an example of a Chinese name `Xi Jinping` where `Xi` is the Lastname - another difficult example.

Comment: phil_t, if you need to ask about complicated names like that, you need to include names like that in your sample input. You have several other types of names (with, without middle; hyphenated; single-name), so adding a few more should suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
gsub("(.*[^van])\\s(.*)", "\\2, \\1", people)
```

The regex:

```
(.*[^van])                                         \\s                      (.*)
Any ammount of characters exluding "van"...  the last white space...  The last name containing any character.
```

Data:

```
people <- c("Barack Obama",
            "Donald J. Trump",
            "J. Edgar Hoover",
            "Beyonce Knowles-Carter",
            "Sting",
            "Ruud van Nistelrooy",
            "Xi Jinping",
            "Hans Zimvanmer")
```

Result:

```
    [1] "Obama, Barack"           "Trump, Donald J."        "Hoover, J. Edgar"       
[4] "Knowles-Carter, Beyonce" "Sting"                   "van Nistelrooy, Ruud"   
[7] "Jinping, Xi"             "Zimvanmer, Hans"
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works for `Donald J. Trump` and `J. Edgar Hoover`? Does the first `(.*)` work for eveything upto the last space?

Comment: Why use `perl=TRUE`? I don't see anything perl-esque about this regex.

Comment: It works without `perl = T` as well? Default has `perl = FALSE`.

Comment: Was a copy and paste result ;)

Comment: this solution is good. But such things are tricky to solve perfectly: `people = "Ruud van Nistelrooy"`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer, how does it know that `\\s` is the last white space and not the first?

Comment: @AndreElrico: Or `Xi Jinping`, where `Xi` is the surname.

Comment: This regex is greedy. It consumes as many characters it can find until it matches. So all whitespaces are consumed until the last one is a possible match. Ruud van Nistelroy works now. Chinese names are of course a challenge. There is no indication of whether a name is chinese or not.

Comment: I'd think the way to work with possible prefixes like that would be to have a list of typical lastname-preceders. I believe this is tenable in many (most? all?) romance languages, but I don't know chinese or such.

Comment: @r2evans I tihnk so, too.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer, the [^van] solution breaks with a middle name that contains "van" like "Robert Donovan Carter". Also, additional special cases are junior/senior and "the second", e.g.  "Jeff Thomas Jr." or "Frank Martinez II".

Comment: Fixed the van issue at least.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer, sorry to keep picking, but that fix doesn't work. `[^van]` doesn't match `"van"`, it matches the single character `"v"` OR `"a"` OR `"n"`. As a result, any middle name ending in v, a or n gets lumped in with the last names (e.g. "Bob Ivan Smith", "Bob Inav Smith", and "Bob Niva Smith" become "Ivan Smith, Bob", "Inav Smith, Bob", and "Niva Smith, Bob", respectively.)

Comment: The solution to the "van" problem would be a negative lookbehind ensuring that the string " van " doesn't precede the break between first and last names. Something like `gsub("(.*)(?<! van| von)\\s(.*)", "\\2, \\1", people, perl = T)`. I like this site for regex questions: https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 6):

There is an esoteric function called `person` designed for holding names, a conversion function `as.person` which does this parsing for you and a `format` method to make use of it afterwards (with a creative use of the braces argument). It even works with complex surnames (eg van Nistelrooy) but the single name result is unsatisfactory. It can fixed with a quick ending `sub` though.

```
x <- c("Barack Obama","Donald J. Trump","J. Edgar Hoover","Beyonce Knowles-Carter","Sting", "Ruud van Nistelrooy", "John von Neumann")
y <- as.person(x)

format(y, include=c("family","given"), braces=list(family=c("",",")))
[1] "Obama, Barack"           "Trump, Donald J."       
[3] "Hoover, J. Edgar"        "Knowles-Carter, Beyonce"
[5] "Sting,"                  "van Nistelrooy, Ruud"   
[7] "von Neumann, John"

## fix for single names - curse you Sting!

sub(",$", "", format(y, include=c("family","given"), braces=list(family=c("",","))))
[1] "Obama, Barack"           "Trump, Donald J."       
[3] "Hoover, J. Edgar"        "Knowles-Carter, Beyonce"
[5] "Sting"                   "van Nistelrooy, Ruud"   
[7] "von Neumann, John"
```

Comment: Wait ... what? R has `person` built-in? Dang, that *seems* rather esoteric ... and yet so very fitting at the moment.